# How to make tkinter Canvas update only on-demand?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I'm writing a graphics program in Python and I would like to know how to make a Canvas update only on-demand; that is, stop a canvas from updating every run of the event loop and instead update only when I tell it to.

I want to do this because in my program I have a separate thread that reads graphics data from standard input to prevent blocking the event loop (given that there's no reliable, portable way to poll standard input in Python, and polling sucks anyway), but I want the screen to be updated only at intervals of a certain amount of time, not whenever the separate thread starts reading input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't pause the update of the canvas without pausing the entire GUI.

A simple solution would be for you to not draw to the canvas until you're ready for the update. Instead of calling canvas commands, push those commands onto a queue. When you're ready to refresh the display, iterate over the commands and run them.

You could also do your own double-buffering, where you have two canvases. The one you are actively drawing would be behind the visible one. When you are ready to display the results, swap the stacking order of the canvases.